# I want the list and details of a s3 trigger mapped with a lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I want the list and details of a s3 trigger mapped with a lambda function. Anyone know to use which boto3 api inorder to obtain the list and details of s3 trigger

Answer (score 0):

That would be the [get_bucket_notification_configuration](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_bucket_notification_configuration) method on the Boto3 S3 client.